# How does svnserve serve up multiple repositories?

Tags: svn, svnserve

I had svnserve configured to look at directory "Foo" for the repository it served. Now I changed the configuration from one repository to multiple repositories, all contained in one directory "Bar". I reconfigured svnserve to look at "Bar", but now my client can't find any repositories. What am I doing wrong? Do I need one service for each repository?

Thanks, Miel.

Comment: How have you configured svnserve "to look at directory "Foo" for the repository it served"? How did you changed the configuration "from one repository to multiple repositories"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you configure your client to use svn://svn-server/Foo ? (Assuming Foo and Foo2 are repositories in directory Bar, which you're serving)

Since you're serving "Bar" now ("svnserve -r /repositories/Bar" instead of "svnserve -r /repositories/Bar/Foo") you should make a change on your client-side repository URL.

Another solution would be to fire up multiple SVN servers with different ports using the --listen-port parameter. That would also change your URL.

Yet another alternative is just adding new projects to your single existing repository; note that you'll have a single repository configuration this way -- and that means a single set of users, simpler access control, etc.

Comment: I was actually pointing to svn://svn-server/Bar/Foo. It wouldn't have occurred to me to leave out the Bar. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html) about svnserve may also come in handy for ya.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [svn switch --relocate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html). That should help you to update the repository path.